# How do I simulate an AJAX request with Flask test client?

Tags: python, ajax, unit-testing, flask

Testing Flask applications is done with:

```
# main.py
from flask import Flask, request

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    s = 'Hello world!', 'AJAX Request: {0}'.format(request.is_xhr)
    print s
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Then here is my test script:

```
# test_script.py
import main
import unittest

class Case(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_index():
        tester = app.test_client()
        rv = tester.get('/')
        assert 'Hello world!' in rv.data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In the test output, I'll get:

```
Hello world! AJAX Request: False
```

## Question

How do I test my app with AJAX requests?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:-

```
def test_index():
    tester = app.test_client()
    response = tester.get('/', headers=[('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')])
    assert 'Hello world!' in response.data
```

Comment: Excellent! :) I was just looking for the parameters I can set for the `.get()` function. I was already digging deep into the `werkzeug` docs :S Which part of the docs did you get this?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/ & http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2011/6/29/werkzeug-client-headers/#d9ba40af5d07413dd75f95f92f515eec

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

def test_index():
    data = json.dumps({})
    client = app.test_client()
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    response = client.post('/', data=data, headers=headers)
    data = json.loads(response.data)
    assert data
```

`